# Restart IIS proces when is memory usage

Tags: powershell, iis, restart

I have a web application and I have one worker process set up. I need to ensure that IIS restarts when the value is exceeded. I am attaching a script below that works for me, but only when I have only one application pool. I am also attaching an error that appears on a server where there are multiple application pools.

```
$process_dump32 = get-process w3wp
$process_dump32_output = [Math]::Round($process_dump32.privatememorysize64, 2)

Write-Output $process_dump32_output


#Email Settings
$EmailBody = 'IIS has more than 800'
$subject_mail = "IIS has more than 800 - $Date"
$MailFrom = 'email@example.com' 
$MailTo = 'email2@example.com'
$smtpServer = '10.0.0.1'
$smtpPort = '587'
$secpasswd1 = ConvertTo-SecureString "Paassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds1 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("notification", $secpasswd1)
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8


If ($process_dump32_output -lt 800000000) 
{  
     #Do Nothing if RAM is less then 800MB
}

Else 
{
     #Stop/Start 
     Stop-Service W3SVC
     Start-Sleep -seconds 5
     Start-Service W3SVC
     
     Send-MailMessage -from $MailFrom -to $MailTo -subject $subject_mail -body $EmailBody -Encoding $encoding -smtpServer $smtpServer -Port $smtpPort -credential $mycreds1
 
     }
```

ERROR

```
Cannot find an overload for "Round" and the argument count: "2".
At I:\MONITOR\check-memory-exception-iis.ps1:7 char:1
+ $process_dump32_output = [Math]::Round($process_dump32.privatememorys ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Thanks for help

**Gild**

Comment: IIS is a multi-process system itself, so you should expect many `w3wp.exe` processes out there and write your script in a compatible way. Besides, use IIS application pool recycle to limit memory usage and configure IIS to write the recycle event log entries. Then you can trigger emails from those Windows event log entries easily. None of that requires this kind of scripting (restarting W3SVC is crazy).

Comment: If you are worrying about the memory usage issue, you could try the suggestions about IIS recycle shared by Lex, the following is a link with the steps you could refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling/